# How can I hide model's item in view ? (MVC5)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-5.2

I work with MVC5 in C#. I use Code First connection. I want hide my model's US_ID component in view. When I click edit button see this [ResultImage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7fz3k.png) result. I want US_ID textbox visible=false. But I can't do it.

I follow below code in my web application :
// I wrote this code in controller

```
        [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult EditUser(WebApplication3.Models.UserAccount usr)
    {
        using (OurDbContext db = new OurDbContext())
        {
            db.Entry<WebApplication3.Models.UserAccount>(usr).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
            name = usr.US_NAME;
            pass = usr.US_PASS;
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

```
<body id="body" style="background-color:#c9d7e8;">
    <div>
        @using (Html.BeginForm())
        {
             @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.US_ID)   
            @Html.EditorForModel("UserAccount")
            <br />
            <input type="submit" value="Yenilə" />
        }
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: The EditorForModel is likely rendering an input for the hidden field; you'd have to define an EditorTemplate for whatever type the model property UserAccount represents.  See this for more information: http://www.growingwiththeweb.com/2012/12/aspnet-mvc-display-and-editor-templates.html

Comment: @Nigar do you need the `US_ID` in the view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put this attribute on top of the property that you do not want to show:

```
[System.Web.Mvc.HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
```